# WPF DataGrid StyleSelector for Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use an ItemContainerStyleSelector to display different row styles in a datagrid, based on the type of the object defining the row (ItemsSource is a collection of `IGridItem`s, there are `GridItem` and `GridSeparator` which should get different styles). my problem was, that the `SelectStyle` of my StyleSelector was never called. Now I found out ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623820/rowstyleselector-not-called)) the problem could be an inherited style (MahApps Metro library redefines the default styles of all standard controls), which probably already sets an ItemContainerStyle.

So now my question is: Is there a way to still use my StyleSelector, so that I have the inherited style as base for the selected styles? And if not, how do I achieve a different style just for some rows based on their object type?

EDIT:
Manually setting the ItemContainerStyle to `null` didn't have an effect, `SelectStyle` of my StyleSelector is still never called.

EDIT2:
Since I don't get `System.Windows.Data Error: 24 : Both 'ItemContainerStyle' and 'ItemContainerStyleSelector' are set; 'ItemContainerStyleSelector' will be ignored.` like Grx70 asked, I assume that the ItemContainerStyle is not the problem, like I initially thought.

jstreet pointed out, that it's related to MahApps.Metro, though... (see his comment)

---

My current implementation:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource StyleSelector}">
```

The Syle selector:

```
public class GridRowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    private readonly ResourceDictionary _dictionary;

    public GridRowStyleSelector()
    {
        _dictionary = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/myApp;component/View/GridResources.xaml")
        };
    }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string name = item?.GetType().Name;
        if (name != null && _dictionary.Contains(name))
        {
            return (Style)_dictionary[name];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

GridResources.xaml with test values:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="GridItem" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="GridSeparator"  TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Just to get it off the table - are you sure `{StaticResource StyleSelector}` resolves to a `GridRowStyleSelector` instance?

Comment: The method signature for Select style is 
public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)

Comment: Furthermore, are you getting a `System.Windows.Data Error: 24 : Both 'ItemContainerStyle' and 'ItemContainerStyleSelector' are set;  'ItemContainerStyleSelector' will be ignored.` error in the output window?

Comment: @Grx70 yea I know that the instance is resolved, since I can break in the constructor, and no, I didn't see that error anywhere

Comment: @Manolo I don't know what you want to tell me with this, this is exactly what I implemented

Comment: @Grx70 but I just noticed that I get a `"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll` every time I rebuild the datagrid contents containing a GridSeparator - haven't noticed that until now, seems to be related

Comment: Indeed, the `StyleSelector.SelectStyle()` method gets called in a regular WPF application, but not when using `MahApps.Metro`. Looks like it's being ignored altogether. BTW, no exceptions at all in either case.

Comment: ok thx for trying this, I edited the tags to include Metro, maybe someone affiliated with it sees this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've found the culprit. Turns out that the proper way to handle row styles in `DataGrid` is through `RowStyle` and `RowStyleSelector` properties and not `ItemContainerStyle` and `ItemContainerStyleSelector`. They work, but only until you explicitly use `RowStyle` or `RowStyleSelector`. That's exactly what MahApps Metro does - it sets `RowStyle` value (I believe through overriding `DataGrid` default style). Then I think `ItemContainerStyle` is set internally by `DataGrid` (some testing revealed that `ItemContainerStyle` was set despite explicitly setting it to `null`).

So to sum up, this should do the trick for you:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          RowStyle="{x:Null}"
          RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource StyleSelector}">
    (...)
</DataGrid>
```

Also, to modify MahApps row style rather than discard it completely you should base your styles on the MahApps one:

```
<Style x:Key="GridItem" TargetType="DataGridRow"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="GridSeparator" TargetType="DataGridRow"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default `ItemContainerStyle` by explicitly setting it to `null`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{x:Null}"
          ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource StyleSelector}">
```

Comment: ok, I tried this, but I still never stop in `SelectStyle`... It seems as if my styleselector has another reason to just be ignored :/

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the GridRowStyleSelector class is static and private. 
Try removing the 'static' keywords from this class, and make the constructor public.

Comment: I still never enter `SelectStyle`... the old constructor works as well as the non-static one, if I set a breakpoint it stops there