# WPF Datagrid DataTrigger based on a variable

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid with a SDate column that shows the Date. I would like to create a triger in Xaml that turns the row green when a date is a certain value. I have this working perfectly:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SDate}" Value="30/12/2016">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

I would now like to alter this trigger to remove the typed date and replace it with a reference a variable that stores the date instead. The variable is already part of my datacontent. Is that possible? Im 3rd day into WPF and may have lost the plot someplace.

Comment: You have to write a StyleSelector for the same

Comment: As @Mohit points yout, you can't actually bind anything to `DataTrigger.Value`. What you should probably do is use a multibinding with a multivalue converter that returns true if the two values bound to the multibinding are true.

Comment: You might be better off binding the color to the date and adding an IValueConverter which takes that date and returns a Brush / Color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with a `MultiBinding` and a multi-value converter:

Converter:

```
public class DateEqualsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDateTime(values[0])
            .Equals(System.Convert.ToDateTime(values[1]));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, 
        Type[] targetTypes, 
        object parameter, 
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Window resources (maybe this is `UserControl.Resources` instead; you didn't say):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateEqualsConverter x:Key="DateEquals" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And here's the `DataTrigger` in the `Style`. I don't know the name of the viewmodel property you're comparing `SDate` to, so I just called it `GreenDate`.

OTOH I'm guessing that "The variable is already part of my datacontent" means that the property is already defined in your viewmodel, and your viewmodel is your `DataContext`. That may be one guess too many. Let me know.

```
<DataTrigger 
    Value="True"
    >
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DateEquals}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="SDate" />
                <Binding Path="GreenDate" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I managed top convert the code to VB, now I stuck with the local: in window resources, this being my 3rd day at WPF Im totaly out of my depth

Comment: I cracked it, the code works perfectly , my referencing and name spaces weren't lining up. Much thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: @user1500403 Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Style Selector for the same.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881121/wpf-datagrid-styleselector-for-rows).

Comment: That cannot be done as disscued here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240421/using-binding-for-the-value-property-of-datatrigger-condition

Comment: My bad: You're absolutely right, it's not possible to put a Binding on `DataTrigger.Value`. Unfortunately it won't let me undo the DV until you edit the answer. OTOH a MultiBinding with a comparison converter would still be better than multiple styles.